# WPF How to make control always on top and stay in the view after user scrolls down

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm building a vertical timeline app using WPF, something like this:
[image]

The app is divided into 2 sides, on the left are the dates in circles, and on the right are the details.

Let's say on my screen I can only see 2 circles on the left, and on the right are some very long details. What I want to achieve is, when I scroll down, the first circle goes up the screen, then gets stuck at the top instead of going out of my view.

It's like Telegram on Android, the sender's display picture will always be on top no matter the user scrolls up or down, till the next sender's display picture comes in.

I hope I'm able to explain myself clearly. I've managed to create the app in WPF, now I would like to do the enhancement mentioned above, but I have no idea where to start.

EDIT:
Here are two images to explain what I want to achieve.

Before scrolling down

[image: Before scrolling down]

After scrolling down

[image: After scrolling down]

Comment: There are no native controls that achieve such a thing, you may have to create your own custom control for this instance.

Answer (score 0):

The very simplest solution that I can think of would be to use a HeaderedItemsControl. This would allow you to set your top item as the header and all the other items as your list items.

```
 <Grid>

        <HeaderedItemsControl>
            <HeaderedItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedItemsControl}">
                    <Border>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" />
                            <!--<Separator Grid.Row="1" />-->
                            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </HeaderedItemsControl.Template>
            <HeaderedItemsControl.Header>Mark</HeaderedItemsControl.Header>
            <HeaderedItemsControl.Items>
                <system:String>Mark2</system:String>
                <system:String>Mark3</system:String>
                <system:String>Mark4</system:String>
                <system:String>Mark5</system:String>
                <system:String>Mark6</system:String>
                <system:String>Mark7</system:String>
                <system:String>Mark7</system:String>
            </HeaderedItemsControl.Items>
        </HeaderedItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```